# Firebase Fido2 Authentication Support

Tags: firebase, fido-u2f, webauthn

I know that Google's Firebase/Firestore platform supports multiple authentication methods/backends, but I'm not currently seeing any option for Fido2 or WebAuthn for Firebase Authentication. Does anyone know if Google has a timeline to release support for Fido2 on their Firebase development platform? Or if it's already available, and I'm just missing something.

I am currently only on the Spark FREE plan, so I don't know if that is a problem.

Any insight or assistance would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

They currently do not support it, and as far as I can tell there's currently no timeline for support. [source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2123)

Google has recently started using the WebAuthn API for authentication of security keys, but not yet for registration. I would guess that Firebase gets passwordless authentication support around the same time that Google accounts do, but I couldn't say if that's 3 months or 3 years away.